# Construction to express: a present perfect action up until now and its future state

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, present-perfect, phrases

*My pool has been closed for 10 days now and will continue (to be closed) for more than 2 weeks.*
Is it correct that way?
Also, is there any construction that would sound better?

Comment: i think "My pool has been shut down for 10 days now , and it will remain shut down for another 2 weeks." would be okay

Comment: That sounds great, thank you

Comment: @ Nadi Mar no problem

Comment: would has been closing for 10 days also fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Moha mentioned in the comments you could use:

> My pool has been shut down for 10 days now, and it will remain shut down for another 2 weeks.

"closed" is a state. and as you probably know we use different forms of the word "to be" to express states in English:

> the pool is closed
>
> the pool was closed
>
> the pool has been closed, so on and so forth.

now you want to express a state in the future, it seems to me the only options that you have are:

1. using will

   - my pool will be/remain closed for another two weeks.

     - indented eight spaces.
2. using be + infinitive  *this is not that common in speaking though

   - my pool is to be/remain closed for another two weeks.
3. using be going to

   - my pool is going to be closed for another two weeks.

as a bonus you could also use "future perfect":

> my pool will have been closed for another 2 weeks [by the time summer ends]
>   *it's recommended to have a time marker with this tense, though it's not mandatory.

More on future perfect:

> When we refer to a future action completed before a later future time,
>   or **a future state continuing up to that later future time**, we use will
>   + have + a past participle (third form). This is sometimes known as the ‘future perfect’:
>
> > I will have lived here for just over thirteen years when I celebrate my 66th birthday next March. (At the moment of speaking, six months before ‘next March’, the speaker has lived ‘here’ for twelve and a half years.)
> >
> > By the time she leaves Paris tomorrow, Emma will have seen Luke and told him the news. (When Emma leaves Paris tomorrow, the seeing and telling will be, for her, in the past.)

ref: https://www.usingenglish.com/articles/ways-expressing-future-in-english.html